# Задача. TCP-протокол. Сколько бит было получено канальным уровнем от физического?

Tags: сеть, tcp, cisco, wireshark, cisco-packet-tracer

Нужно узнать сколько бит передал физический уровень канальному уровню, исходя только из данных на скриншоте. Правильно ли я понимаю, что нужно подсчитать вес TCP заголовка и полезной нагрузки?[image: Скриншот_Wireshark]

Буквальная постановка задачи "Компьютер получил данные. Запишите сколько было получено бит канальным уровнем от физического", задание из зачета по сетевым технологиям

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! [пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119)

Comment: TCP не является протоколом канального уровня, поэтому из данных на скриншоте сделать это невозможно

Comment: Да и в целом задача выглядит не очень осмысленной. Физический уровень добавляет дополнительные биты для защиты от искажения сигнала — нужно ли их считать?

Comment: Задание из зачета по сетевым технологиям, постановка задачи именно такая "Компьютер получил данные. Запишите сколько было получено бит канальным уровнем от физического"